# Github REST Api get workflow runs for a specific date range with cURL

Tags: rest, github, curl, github-actions, github-api

I am trying to query Github's REST API to list workflow runs for specific date ranges.

Here's an example curl call:

```bash
curl \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/[OWNER]/[REPO]/actions/runs?created:2023-01-01..2023-01-02"
```

From what I understand from the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository), this is how I should be able to retrieve only results from Jan 1st and 2nd of 2023. But it does not work, my result is always the latest runs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the `=` symbol instead of `:`, like:

```
 curl \                                                                                                
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/[OWNER]/[REPO]/actions/runs?created=2023-01-01..2023-01-02"
```

Comment: It actually is a colon `:`. See [Query for dates](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-dates).

Comment: @Azeem the doc is referring at the website search (not the rest api) just as an example. My answer reflect something that I've tested (and works for me)

Comment: That's strange. Its link is listed under `created` in [List workflow runs for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository).

Comment: yes, a bit strange and misleading...

Comment: +1. `created=start..end` is working fine. Verified: `curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" "https://api.github.com/repos/iamazeem/test/actions/runs?created=2023-02-11..2023-02-13" | jq .total_count`

Comment: thank you both, this actually works. I'm sure I've tried the `=` but I must have missed something. And yes, the docs link is quite misleading. It got me more confused than it helped.

Comment: Issue created on GHA docs repo: https://github.com/github/docs/issues/23882. Feel free to add more details if needed. Thanks!